# Trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop, screen gets stuck in vertical mode, and wont rotate out of it

Tags: intel-graphics, gpu, display-rotation

So im trying to install Ubuntu on a laptop of mine, i had been running Debain, and my GF will now be using it. So i wanted something i little more user friendly for here. However, for some reason when i try the live version on this laptop, it boots up in vertical orientation, and i can't rotate out in the quick menu or via settings.

Also tried tinkering with the screen in terminal, to no avail.

The issue i think is this laptop is a flip screen one, specs below, you typically use it like a laptop but you can flip the screen over and use the touch screen capabilities. Its almost like ubuntu thinks its a tablet.

Specs: 
ASUS Q552U Laptop/Core i7-6500U 2.50 GHz/1TB HDD/12GB RAM/15.6in/940M(GPU)

Comment: Telling us the release of Ubuntu would be a start.  Is it a release using as a desktop Unity (14.04 LTS or 16.04 LTS), GNOME (18.04 LTS & 18.10) or even a flavor (in which case what release & flavor).  I've assumed its a desktop release, and not server, IoT or other releases.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue when I first switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.10 on my laptop. What worked for me was opening up terminal and then entering

`xrandr --listmonitors` At the bottom line on the far right you should get the code for your monitor (for me it said "eDP-1-1") Take that code and put it into

`xrandr --output <code> --rotate normal`

If the problem comes up each time you reboot, put the command into a bash file and put that file in Startup Applications.